# On the density of the orders excluded by the Sylow theorems for simple groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

If $G$ is a finite group whose order is divisible by a prime $p$ and $p^r$ is the maximal power of $p$ that divides it, the Sylow theorems tell us that the number $n_p$ of Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ is congruent to $1$ modulo $p$ and a divisor of $\lvert G\rvert/p^r$, and that if $n_p=1$ then $G$ is not simple. With this information alone we can decide that some numbers are not the order of a finite simple group.

> How big is the set of numbers that these two facts exclude as candidates to be the order of a simple group?

By *big* here one can mean, say, the density in $\mathbb{N}$. One can also weigh numbers by the number of actual groups of each order, so as to turn the question into

> What proportion of finite groups are known to be non-simple by using only these two Sylow theorems on the number of they Sylow subgroups?

Since most groups are apparently $p$-groups, the answer to this is probably one.

Comment: Probably the (conjectural) answer to the second question will be: proportion 1, just because among groups, those that are 2-groups are preponderant, and are covered by this result as non-(simple non-abelian). The first question is possibly more interesting and it would be useful to define more formally this set of integers without reference to groups.

Comment: Yup, by zero I meant one :-)

Comment: It seems that Will Sawin used one group-free definition of this set: the set $W$ of $n$ such that for every prime divisor $p$ of $n$, there exists $a\ge 1$ such that $1+ap$ divides $n$, and shows $W$ has natural density $0$. (I don't know if there other orders that can be easily ruled out using Sylow's theorems.)

Comment: I checked a little more: many numbers $n$ are in $W$ but can be ruled out using Sylow's theorems too, e.g., $n=12$. Also $n=4.3^m$ for $m\ge 2$ is ruled out because $n_3=4$ means a nontrivial homomorphism $G\to S_4$, which can't be injective; similarly $n=3.2^m$ is ruled out getting a homomorphism $G\to S_3$. $n=30$, $n=105$ (which are in $W$) are ruled out just counting elements of Sylows, there are too many.

Comment: @YCor, indeed, the Sylow theorems allow us to rule out many other orders, but my question was really only about those orders that are ruled out by the two facts I mentioned, the complement of W. These are the orders that get excluded with least effort, if you want.

Comment: OK I see, and this is indeed enough to get density 0. (BTW, independently of Sylow, with least effort (both in the proof and in checking), you exclude orders $>2$ equal to $2$ modulo $4$.)

Answer (score 12):

Such numbers have density $1$. In fact, for a density $1$ set of numbers it suffices to apply Sylow's theorem to the largest prime factor.

In other words, for a density $1$ set of numbers $n$, with $p$ the largest prime factor of $n$, there is no number congruent to $1$ mod $p$ dividing $n$ other than $1$.

Proof: We start from a classical fact of analytic number theory, that for each $\epsilon>0$ there is $\delta>0$ such that a density $1-\epsilon$ fraction of numbers have a prime factor of size $>n^{\delta}$. So it suffices to restrict attention to numbers with a prime factor of size $n^{\delta}$.

The number of numbers between $X$ and $2X$ which have a large prime factor do not satisfy the condition is at most the number of triples $p,a,b$ where $p> X^{\delta}$ is prime, $a>0$, and $$X< p (1+pa) b< 2X$$

Indeed, take $p$ to be the largest prime factor, $1+pa$ a nontrivial divisor congruent to $1$ mod $p$, and $b$ to be whatever factor remains.

Now note that for each $p,a$, the number of possible values of $b$ is at most $\frac{2 X}{ p (1+pa) }\leq \frac{2X}{p^2 a}$. Summing over $a$ from $1$ to $X$, the number of such triples with fixed $p$ is $O ( \frac{X }{p^2} \log X)$ by the harmonic series. Summing over $p$ from $X^\delta$ to $\infty$, the number of such triples is $O( \frac{X \log X}{ X^{\delta}} ) = o(X)$ so the set of numbers not satisfying the condition has density zero, as desired.